# Why is AWS S3 Object count is measured iin units used to measure file size?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, files

In AWS, the files/objects are stored in S3 bucket and the files/object count should list the total no of files/objects stored in S3 bucket as an INTEGER value.

But I see the S3 object count as floating value and the unit represented is letter 'G' like below in AWS S3 dashboard. Why is the unit used to represent object count has the unit used to represent the file size? if this is not the unit like GB/MB/KB then what's the unit mentioned to represent "Object count" in AWS S3? Can anyone explain?

```
Object count    2.2 G
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have shown a screenshot of your Storage Lens account snapshot, which gives you a summary of what is in all the S3 buckets in your account.

You can see that you have consumed 3.2 petabytes of storage using 2.3 billion objects with an average object size of 1.5 megabytes.

In this case the G simply means giga, or billion.

Comment: Hampthon - thanks a lot.

Comment: Why in the world did somebody think that "2.3 G" was more intuitive than "2.3 B"...